# Please help me figure out this data. I am trying to calculate CTR(click through rate). Should I be grouping by the CampaignId?

Tags: subquery

my data looks like this:
[image]

[image]

I am trying to calculate CTR, but nor sure how to group it to show some kind of KPI (also open to suggestions on what should I present).

```
SELECT click_n, imp_n, CAST(((click_n/imp_n)*100) AS decimal(8,4) ) as "ctr" 
FROM(
     (SELECT "CampaignId", count("ClickId") as click_n
      FROM "allclicks"
      WHERE "ClickId" IS NOT NULL
      GROUP BY "CampaignId")b JOIN
     (SELECT "CampaignId", count("ImpressionId") as imp_n
      FROM "impressions"
      WHERE "ImpressionId" IS NOT NULL
      GROUP BY "CampaignId")a 
      ON(b."CampaignId"=a."CampaignId"));
```

I am pretty sure my code is wrong, in the values I use. There are so many impressions that the CTR is less than 0.0000% all the time. Please help

Comment: You could improve your question by editing it to include table DDL instead of a hard-to-read image, and specifying the database product you are using in the tags e.g. [tag:mysql]

Answer (score 2):

How types are casted is probably dependent on the DBMS, but a/b may very well be integer division. Try to do an implicit cast by multiplying with 100.0 before division like:

```
SELECT click_n
     , imp_n
     , CAST(((100.0*click_n/imp_n)) AS decimal(8,4) ) as ctr 
FROM (
    (SELECT CampaignId, count(ClickId) as click_n
    FROM allclicks
    WHERE ClickId IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY CampaignId) b
    JOIN 
    (SELECT CampaignId, count(ImpressionId) as imp_n
    FROM impressions
    WHERE ImpressionId IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY CampaignId) a
        ON a.CampaignId = b.CampaignId
)
```

I believe your query should be safe regarding division by 0, but I usually add a test for that in dividends just in case:

```
SELECT click_n
     , imp_n
     , CAST(((100.0*click_n/NULLIF(imp_n,0))) AS decimal(8,4) ) as ctr 
FROM (
    (SELECT CampaignId, count(ClickId) as click_n
    FROM allclicks
    WHERE ClickId IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY CampaignId) b
    JOIN 
    (SELECT CampaignId, count(ImpressionId) as imp_n
    FROM impressions
    WHERE ImpressionId IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY CampaignId) a
        ON a.CampaignId = b.CampaignId
)
```

NULLIF returns null if the first and second argument is equal, which means that the whole expression becomes null instead of division by zero.

For future posts, it is considered much better to post `CREATE TABLE`- and `INSERT`- statements instead of images. Even better is to use a site such as [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) and a create a setup so it is easy to reproduce the problem for anyone willing to take a stab.